# Show/Hide div below link

Tags: jquery

I have a few links on a page all with the same class "expand-content-link" which are all directly above a div with some content in it , set to "display:none;" (with the same class "hidden-content").

I want to be able to click the link and only the div below the link toggles to visible.

HTML

```
<div class="content-holder">
<a href="#" class="expand-content-link">Expand Content 1</a>
<div class="hidden-content">Bunch of hidden content and stuff here</div>
</div>

<div class="content-holder">
<a href="#" class="expand-content-link">Expand Content 2</a>
<div class="hidden-content">Bunch of hidden content for div 2</div>
</div>

<div class="content-holder">
<a href="#" class="expand-content-link">Expand Content 3</a>
<div class="hidden-content">Bunch of hidden content for div 3</div>
</div>
```

Now my javascript is as follows, but it currently expands all content with the class "hidden-content" (for obvious reasons) and I can't figure out how to manipulate the code so it only displays the content that it needs too.

javascript:

```
 <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
        jQuery(".expand-content-link").click(function() {
            jQuery(".content-holder").find(".hidden-content", this).toggle();
            return false;   
        });
    });
</script>
```

JSFIDDLE DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/PsAh9/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `this` to get the item that was clicked, and traverse the DOM from there to the element you want to act on.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery(".expand-content-link").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).next(".hidden-content").toggle();
        return false;   
    });
});
```

You might be able to make it a little more resilient to html changes by going up to the parent div, then finding the content div:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery(".expand-content-link").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).closest('.content-holder').find(".hidden-content").toggle();
        return false;   
    });
});
```

Or assuming the content div will be a sibling, but not necessarily after the link:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery(".expand-content-link").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).siblings(".hidden-content").toggle();
        return false;   
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome. Using .next() to select the following element worked a charm. I am OK with jQuery but no expert. Thanks for the speedy response! Truly appreciated Jason.

Comment: There's also `$(this).parent().find(".hidden-content")`, if you're listing all possible ways.

Comment: @Richard I think I could be here all night if I wanted to list **all** the ways. Moral of the story (and the answer to his real underlying question): Start with `this`, then traverse the DOM.

Comment: @JasonP Agreed.  I personally like the second method since that "<a>" tag may end up being nested in more HTML elements.  It ensures that messing with the HTML structure won't mess up the click functionality.  +1

Comment: @Richard I agree, I prefer `parent().find()` or `closest().find()` personally.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't exactly what you asked, but I would do this:

```
<div class="content-holder">
    Expand Content 2
    <div class="hidden-content">Bunch of hidden content for div 2</div>
</div>
```

Drop the <a> and then:

```
$(".content-holder").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".hidden-content").toggle(); 
});
```

That would turn the entire area into the show/hide functionality.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Rqqd/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `next`.

```
jQuery(".expand-content-link").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).next('.hidden-content').toggle();
    return false;
}
```

Also, rather than `href="#"`, use `href="#null"` - a single `#` will jump to the top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/dangoodspeed/M3ZhV/ and here's the code:

```
$(function() {
    var curPage="";
    $("#menu a").click(function() {
       if (curPage.length) { 
            $("#"+curPage).hide();
        }
        curPage=$(this).data("page");
        $("#"+curPage).show();
    });
});
```